# How can I create a component that doesn't change when its address changes within the React Router DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am writing a navigator component. This component uses `useNavigate`. But `useNavigate` can be used inside `react-router-dom`. However, we know that independent components that are not affected by the router must be created outside the router.

How can I create a component that doesn't change when its address changes within the `react-router-dom`?

This is my code:

```js
...
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      // Where can I add fixed components?
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
      <Route path="503" element={<ServiceUnavailable />}></Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />}></Route>
    </>
  )
);

return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
```

I also tried `BrowserRouter`, but I got `useEffect` error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "fixed" components for a set of routes then render these on a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes). Layout routes render "fixed" content and an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) for nested routes to render their `element` into.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    {/* Render fixed components like Navbars in layout */}
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="503" element={<ServiceUnavailable />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
```